# The problem of rebuilding the widget tree when the text field has focus

Tags: flutter, performance, focus, textfield, rebuild

When the text field has focus, the inner widgets are continuously rebuilt.
I solved this problem when I navigate from one screen (context) to another screen (another context), by taking focus from the text field.
I wanted to know what is your solution?

How do you interact with text fields?
Do you use the `onChange()` method of the text field?
Do you use a `TextEditingController`?
When do you give focus and when do you take focus from the text field?
How to prevent rebuilding Widget Tree when using a text field?